# Python :Implementing Linkedlist using multipel classes

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I am pretty sure that there is some silly mistake but I haven't been able to figure it out.
I wish to implement a linked list. I have a class for implementing nodes which I use in one of the function for linkedList when I have to push a new node. Here is the code(avoid the faulty indentation)

```
class LinkedList():

def __init__(self, head=None):
    self.head = head

def insert(self, data):
    new_node = Node(data)
    new_node.set_next(self.head)
    self.head = new_node



class Node():
  def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
    self.data = data
    self.next_node = next_node

def get_data(self):
    return self.data

def get_next(self):
    return self.next_node

def set_next(self, new_next):
    self.next_node = new_next
```

But on trying to get an instance of the linkedList in PyCharm console this is what I get

```
import linkedList
a=LinkedList()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'LinkedList' is not defined
```

Any ideas where I might be screwing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `import linkedList` you import the module which I guess contains the code you posted in your question. You will need to use the `linkedList` namespace to access the module contents.

So `a=LinkedList()` won't work, but `a=linkedList.LinkedList()` should work.

If you want to add the `LinkedList` definition from your module to your current global namespace, you can also do the following:

```
from linkedList import LinkedList
a = LinkedList()
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html